Casting to LPPOINT
Is casting a POINT argument to LPPOINT needed or not in the following scenario:
POINT point;
ClientToScreen(somehwnd, (LPPOINT) &point);

Or is the following enough:
POINT point;
ClientToScreen(somehwnd, &point);

This Win32 document uses a cast, whereas this Win32 document does not use a cast.

I don't know what TPOINT is. Does your compiler complain?

TPOINT is different from POINT I assume.

If the leading T in TPOINT is a typo, and it's really just POINT, then no explicit conversion (cast) is needed. Otherwise, what is TPOINT?

Neither of the pages you linked mentions "TPOINT".

Lapsus calami, now edited to use POINT.

If you are using 16-bit Windows, LPPOINT was a far pointer and this cast does do something. I think that conversion was implicitly done anyways so it would still work if the cast was removed

LPPOINT is a type alias for POINT*. The expression &point has the type POINT*. A cast is not required.

Not only not required, but wrong. The cast in the linked document "(LPPOINT)NULL" is also not needed, NULL by itself is fine.

@SoronelHaetir Casting the type of an expression to the same type is never required but also never wrong.

@IInspectable -- never wrong semantically, but definitely wrong if you don't want to confuse future readers of your code (including your future self). Of course, it could certainly be fixed with a comment: // ignore this cast; it isn't meant to do anything meaningful. 

@PeteBecker There's a difference between "confusing" and "wrong". I addressed the statement that claimed the cast was wrong. That statement isn't true and it's important to call out that casting an expression to the same type is legal and has no effect. While of little practical use here, you'll inevitably need to know this when authoring or reviewing class or function templates.
